# Add class and href to a button in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, addition

I hope ant one can help.
Must be easy but could not find an easy fix? How can I add an Class and href attribute to the button I just put into my game?

```
       displayScore: function() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Game Over</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2> Your score is: " + 
                    quiz.score + 
                    "</h2><br>" + 
                    "<a><button>Play again</button></a>";
    this.populateIdWithHTML("quiz", gameOverHTML);
},

populateIdWithHTML: function(id, text) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.innerHTML = text;
},
```

Comment: Do you know how to place those attributes when you are writing html? If not see the mozilla developer network for the appropriate tutorial. If you do it's the same way you would do it here.

Comment: If you require href to outer page then you have to add `<a></a>` OR If inside the same page then you can handle it using JavaScript.

Comment: Who told you that you need a button with a href? Maybe it'd be better if you ask about your original problem and not about the assumed solution!

Comment: Thank you for the qwick response.
I know how to place the <a></a> atributes.
This problem is now buggin mee for hourse ...

I want to include the ahref and button class into the string I send to the dom is this posible.

Answer (score 0):

With class you could try doing it with jQuery. First import the jQuery CDN in your project and do this:

```
$( "#youbuttonID" ).addClass( "class you want to add" );
```

Comment: Thank you.
But I am looking for a way how to direcly add a class to the button and put a value in the <a></a> element.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this..

```
        <button><a href="#">Play again</a></button>

         $("button").addClass("name of class to be added ");
```

Hope it would work.

Comment: I try to do this in javascript without using Jqwery

Comment: or you can do it like this

Comment: @Amadeo ..i have posted another answer..just have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="name of class to be added "><button><a href="#">Play again</a></button></div>
```

this is gonna work

Comment: Thank you but the string is not accepting any attributes.

Comment: then why dont you use jquery..its too easy

Comment: hey ..dont make it complicated...just add the CDN link and get started with cool jquery code

Comment: I try to find a solution in javascript. But also the solution posted in Jqwery is not working inforiantly

Comment: It will work.. add this link in your head tag  and use that jquery code                                       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>